# "command not found" when using arithmetic expansion in bash shell

Tags: command-line, bash

Using Ubuntu Desktop, I have terminal open and I am using the bash shell. One of the shell expansions of bash is the arithmetic expansion, with the following syntax:

```
$(( EXPRESSION ))
or 
$[ EXPRESSION ]
```

When i do arithmetic, it does return the correct value but it is always followed by "command not found":

```
$ $((1+2))
3: command not found
$ $[1+2]
3: command not found
$ $[2+2]
4: command not found
$ $((2*6))
12: command not found
```

My question is why does it display "command not found" and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `echo` command before all of your commands,

```
$ echo $[1+2]
3
```

You don't have to put directly `$[1+2]` on terminal, because bash computes `$[1+2]` and again parses the same, so command not found error occurs.

#### For Example

```
$ var="sudo apt-get update"
$ $var

Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease                               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                                   
Ign http://ubuntu.inode.at saucy InRelease                          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                        
29% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]
```

In the above example, `sudo apt-get update` command was assigned to a variable `var`.On running `$var`, first bash expands it and again parses the expanded one.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ $((1+2))
3: command not found
```

What is happening here is that `bash` computes `$((1+2))` which results in `3`.  `bash` then looks for a command named `3` to execute.  It doesn't find it.  Hence the error.  As @Avinash suggests, use `echo` to avoid this.

```
$ echo  $((1+2))
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `bash` is trying to execute the output of your expansion and it doesnt find any `command` with name `3` in the `PATH`. To just try out, use `echo` or assign it to a variable and use it later.

```
echo $((1+2))
3
test=$((1+2))
echo $test
3
```